# Visio Hyperlinks query

Tags: vba, sharepoint, visio

The users have documents in Sharepoint document library. I need to be able to get the urls of these documents easy within Visio. Would I need to write something in VBA which gets the urls of these documents from Sharepoint, or is there an easier option ?

I have looked at the net use command so they can map a drive but that does not give the url.

anyone done anything like this before ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint exposes XML interfaces that you can use to determine elements in a table or items in a library (which is a known and static location in SharePoint).

What you can use and how you access it will depend on your version of SharePoint and how it is configured on your network. However, there are plenty of examples on the internet that you can search in your favourite search engine (Alta Vista anyone?) which will get you started with some code. I expect you will have some specific questions once you start coding.

It has been a while since I did this.